# Is there a way to find specific sub folders in a directory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I have a Python program where I'm searching through a directory but for certain sub folders in that directory I want to delete files in them if they were created for more than 7 days and the rest of the files in the directory delete if they were created more than 21 days.

So after the local user are company folders and inside that folders are sub folders that I need such as House, Address, And Phone any suggestion?

```
import os
from datetime import date,timedelta,datetime
import time
 
#Path for the employee files
path ="C:/inetpub/ftproot/LocalUser/"

#Function to delete the files
def deleteFiles(days,path):
   #Set time Value (86400 secs in 24 hours)
   current_time = time.time()
   time_in_secs = current_time - (days * 86400)
   # Check to see if the path exists
   if os.path.exists(path):
       for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(root,file)
            file_status = os.stat(full_path)
            #print( full_path)

            if(current_time - file_status.st_mtime) // (86400) >= days:
                print(full_path)
                #os.remove(full_path)
                #print(full_path + "\nhas been deleted")
   else:
      print("Error Path Doesn't Exist!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        
        
   deleteFiles(7,path)
```

Comment: Could you please share the file directory structure?

Comment: @IsseiKumagai   C:\inetpub\ftproot\LocalUser\Company folders\House Folder, files, and more folders

Comment: what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @Andreas there is no problem I just need to filter out my sub folders where I can find a way to delete them. That's all what I'm asking.

Comment: are u asking for a way to delte folders or to os.walk() only thorugh specific folder?

Comment: to walk through specific folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first create a list of white_listed folders, and then iterate through the files in them like this:

```
import os
from datetime import date,timedelta,datetime
import time

path = r"C:/inetpub/ftproot/LocalUser/"
white_list = ["House", "Address"]

lst_white_folder = []
if os.path.exists(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if os.path.split(root)[-1] in white_list:
            # print(os.path.split(root)[-1])
            lst_white_folder.append(root)

# alternatively you could provide the listof folderpaths directly of course
for folder_path in lst_white_folder:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            print(file)
            #do something
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I'll test it in the morning

Comment: question for you?

Comment: @Sdot2323 what do u mean?

Comment: I think I figured it out by using the "if  root.endswith("House") " @Andrea

Comment: That will work, but be aware if you have subfolder with the same name it gets tricky. Example could be New Folder etc. Anyway glad u could solve it. HappyCoding!

Comment: No its one way, the first part loops through the folders and gets the path of the relevant folders and puts them into a list. The second part then loops through all folders which are in the previously created list and only there looks for files. Its more complicated than just doing the root.endswith() aproach but propably a bit safer for complex folder structures.